# Matching MD5 Hashes from another script

Tags: python, hash, md5

Ok so i'm trying to create a script that does the following: Searches a directory for known hashes. Here is my first script:

Hash.py

```
import hashlib

from functools import partial

#call another python script
execfile("knownHashes.py")

def md5sum(filename):
    with open(filename, mode='rb') as f:
        d = hashlib.md5()
        for buf in iter(partial(f.read, 128), b''):
            d.update(buf)
    return d.hexdigest()
print "Hash of is: "
print(md5sum('photo.jpg'))

if md5List == md5sum:
    print "Match"
```

knownHashes.py

```
print ("Call worked\n")

md5List = "01071709f67193b295beb7eab6e66646" + "5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592"
```

The problem at the moment is that I manually have to type in the file I want to find out the hash of where it says photo.jpg. Also, The I haven't got the md5List to work yet.

I want the script to eventually work like this:

```
python hash.py <directory>
1 match 
cookies.jpg matches hash
```

So how can I get the script to search a directory rather than manually type in what file to hash? Also, how can I fix the md5List because that is wrong?

Comment: First, why do you need the md5list to be in a separate script? Isn't it easier to fill up a file with the known md5's and then reading them in an array?

Comment: @BubbleMonster you should change your question title to actually reflect the question you are asking and also probably remove most of the code you posted since it isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of files in the current working directory using the following. This is the directory that you run the script from.

```
import os

#Get list of files in working directory
files_list = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
```

You can iterate through the list using a for loop:

```
for file in files_list:
    #do something
```

As equinoxel also mentioned below, you can use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.walk) as well.

Comment: or use `os.walk()` if you want to scan a directory and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Simple little gist should solve most of your problems. Understandable if you don't like using OOP for this problem, but I believe all of the important conceptual pieces are here in a pretty clean, concise representation. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
class PyGrep:

    def __init__(self, directory):
        self.directory = directory

    def grab_all_files_with_ending(self, file_ending):
        """Will return absolute paths to all files with given file ending in self.directory"""
        walk_results = os.walk(self.directory)
        file_check = lambda walk: len(walk[2]) > 0
        ending_prelim = lambda walk: file_ending in " ".join(walk[2])
        relevant_results = (entry for entry in walk_results if file_check(entry) and ending_prelim(entry))
        return (self.grab_files_from_os_walk(result, file_ending) for result in relevant_results)

    def grab_files_from_os_walk(self, os_walk_tuple, file_ending):
        format_check = lambda file_name: file_ending in file_name
        directory, subfolders, file_paths = os_walk_tuple
        return [os.path.join(directory, file_path) for file_path in file_paths if format_check(file_path)]
```